# wget -o command output generates more than one file, is it possible to get only one?

Tags: linux, wget

I am executing the "wget -o  " and because the output is bigger than expected, it is split in more than one file. Is there a way to get only one file? If this is possible I would prefer to use only the command wget.

The command wget that I am executing is:

```
$  wget -o neighborhoods.json https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mongodb/docs-assets/geospatial/neighborhoods.json
```

And the multiple output is:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu    6652 Mar  4 01:15 neighborhoods.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 4137081 Mar  4 01:15 neighborhoods.json.1
```

Comment: `-o` logs messages. It sounds like you only want the JSON data, so use `wget -O neighborhoods.json https://....` Check `man wget` for the difference between them.

Comment: If you do intend to log the messages form wget, maybe use `-o` messages.log and additionally use `-O neighborhoods.json` to specify an output log for the JSON.

Comment: yes... you are right, it was my mistake and I wanted to use the -O option

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: ok, thanks for clarify this. Do you suggest that I should delete the questions?

Answer (score -1):

Look well at the wget output, you will see what it is/will be doing. wget does not split files if they are long; instead, it avoids to *overwrite* files, if they exist (creating a new file instead of touching the already existing one).

Delete the two files neighborXXX, and start wget again; be sure it finishes without problems: it will write (create) the single file you asked for. If it is interrupted, and you restart it, it will create a new file (appending .1 and so on).

You can pass it the option `-c` to tell it to *continue* a broken download, if it was interrupted - most of the times it works well (not always tough).